# Item (Magento\Customer\Model\Customer\Interceptor) with the same ID "6827" already exists

Tags: magento2

I am facing the below problem when requesting the customer list:

Critical: Report ID: webapi-600ad6e880167; Message: Item (Magento\Customer\Model\Customer\Interceptor) with the same ID "6827" already exists.

Request URI: /index.php/rest/V1/customers/search?searchCriteria%5Bfilter_groups%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfield%5D=updated_at&searchCriteria%5Bfilter_groups%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=2021-01-01%2009:23:26&searchCriteria%5Bfilter_groups%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcondition_type%5D=gt&searchCriteria%5Bsort_orders%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfield%5D=updated_at&searchCriteria%5Bsort_orders%5D%5B0%5D%5Bdirection%5D=ASC&searchCriteria%5Bpage_size%5D=101&searchCriteria%5Bcurrent_page%5D=1

[2021-01-22 15:18:23] main.CRITICAL: Report ID: webapi-600aecbf05b0d; Message: Item (Magento\Customer\Model\Customer\Interceptor) with the same ID "6827" already exists. {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Report ID: webapi-600aecbf05b0d; Message: Item (Magento\Customer\Model\Customer\Interceptor) with the same ID "6827" already exists. at /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php:208, Exception(code: 0): Item (Magento\Customer\Model\Customer\Interceptor) with the same ID "6827" already exists. at /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection.php:408)"} []

I have no clue how to fix this? The customer indeed exists when looking up the ID in the backend, but I cant seem to find any duplicate IDs. Can I somehow debug it further to know in which table I need to look?

Thanks!

Comment: Would be great if someone can help me debug it.. Spend a lot of hours already..

Comment: what was the solution or action you made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently ran in to this problem.
It was caused by duplicate newsletter subscribers.
Because of this the MySQL join resulted in two customer records being returned with the same ID when searching in the customer repository via the API.

Comment: This was it indeed! Eventually found out but didn't update it here, so accepted your answer! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I think some issue happen on join  collection,

Go to

```
\Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository::getList
```

and after `$this->collectionProcessor->process($searchCriteria, $collection);` and print the sql query   using  `$collection->getSelect()->__toString()`. `__toString()` give  sql query and run query  and you can find `6827` has duplicated record. and your need to  delete repective duplicate data.  That will be resolved that  issue.

**Or**

temp solution is   after `$this->collectionProcessor->process($searchCriteria, $collection);` that  add below code `$collection->getSelect()->group('e.entity_id')`

Comment: Thanks Amit! Will this print the query in a Magento log file?

Comment: echoing `echo $collection->getSelect()->__toString()`

Comment: Mm I dont seem to get anything as output in the log files. I have this now:

        $this->collectionProcessor->process($searchCriteria, $collection);

        echo $collection->getSelect()->__toString();

        $searchResults->setTotalCount($collection->getSize());

Comment: I guess this is it?

`
[2021-01-26 15:59:34] main.DEBUG: SQL Select:  ["(website_id = :website_id)","AND (dest_country_id = :country_id AND dest_region_id = :region_id AND STRCMP(LOWER(dest_city),LOWER(:city))= 0  AND :postcode LIKE dest_zip )","AND (condition_name = :condition_name)","AND (condition_from_value < :condition_value)","AND (condition_to_value >= :condition_value)"] []
`